# I've tried setting up my Canvas in JavaScript and it isn't working

Tags: javascript

I've restarted about 5 times and it's not working. I'm trying to set up my canvas. The first part is the code in the js file and the second code is what I put in the HTML file.

JS:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var w = 1000;
var h = 600;


function setUpCanvas(){
    canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.style.border = "5px dotted orange";
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "m4.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container">
            <h1> module 4 : arrays and loops</h1>
            <canvas id = "myCanvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script src = "m4.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setUpCanvas` isn't called and it isn't closed properly. You're missing the closing brace.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, it works.
for proof, visit

https://loading.hermanboxcar5.repl.co

ok if you do ctrl u on that website it will give you the code you did (except my js file is named `script.js`).
My best guess so far is after the last line of your js put a `}`